# The following code produces the error: local variable 'valid_num2' and 'valid_num2' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import re
def Calculator():    
    raw_input=input("Please enter the calculation you wish to be performed in the necesseary roman numeral format (e.g II + IV ensuring a space between each number and sign): ") #Here we ask for the desired calculation the user wishes to complete

    # assume arguments in the format "VII +II"
    arguments= raw_input.split(" ") #The initial string is then split into three seperate arguments for each separate entity involved in the calculation.
    num1=arguments[0]
    operator = arguments[1] #This indicates that the operator/Command is the second place of our users input which in pyton indices is the 1 space
    num2 = arguments[2] 

    def Validating(num1):
        return (re.search(r"^M{0,3}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$",num1))\
    
    if Validating(num1):
        if Validating(num2):
            print('Both Numerals accepted')
            valid_num1=num1
            valid_num2=num2
        else:
            print('The second numeral entered', num2, 'is not a valid numeral please try again!')
            Calculator()
    else:
        if Validating(num2):
            print("The first numeral entered", num1, "is not a valid numeral please try again!")
            Calculator()
        else:
            print('Both numerals entered', num1, 'and', num2, 'are invalid please try again!')
            Calculator()


    def romanToInt(num1): #This function is essential to the running of the calculator as it converts our first number in our calculations from its roman numeral form to its numerical form 
        #When using roman numerals if the larger numeral comes before the smaller numeral we add them
        #If the smaller numeral comes before larger number we subtract
        
            roman= { "I" : 1, "V" : 5, "X" : 10, "L" : 50, "C" : 100, "D" : 500, "M" : 1000 } #Here we pair each base roman numeral with its numerical counterpart
        
            Int=0
        
            for i in range(len(num1)):
                if i+1<len(num1) and roman[num1[i]] < roman[num1[i+1]]:    #i+1<len(num1) checks to see whether the roman numeral present has another roman numeral after it in our order 
                    Int-=roman[num1[i]]    #roman[num1[i]] < roman[num1[i+1]] this compares whether the first roman numeral is larger or smaller than the one that follows. This is extremely important in determining the value of our roman numerals
                else:    #Int-=roman[s[i]] indicates that in this circumstance we must subtract the first roman numeral from our result
                        Int += roman[num1[i]]     #Int +=roman[num1[i]] indicates that if the previous conditions are not met then we are okay to add both roman numerals together
            return Int #After inserting our roman numeral we are left with an integer as our output

    Int1=romanToInt(valid_num1)
    Int2=romanToInt(valid_num2)

    print(Int1)
    print(Int2)
    print(operator)
    
Calculator()
```

I'm trying to write a code that validates whether the two roman numerals entered within the calculation inputted by the user are correct and then converted into their corresponding integer when both are valid. However I keep on receiving the error previously mentioned. If I remove this bit of code the function below converts all inputs of num1 and num2 even if they have been found to not be valid numerals. How do I go about fixing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The complete error code is as follows:

```
   52     print(Int2)
     53     print(operator)
---> 55 **Calculator()**

Input In [13], in Calculator()
     28         print('Both numerals entered', num1, 'and', num2, 'are invalid please try again!')
     29         Calculator()
---> 31 **num2=valid_num2**
     32 num1=valid_num1
     33 def romanToInt(num1): #This function is essential to the running of the calculator as it converts our first number in our calculations from its roman numeral form to its numerical form 
     34     #When using roman numerals if the larger numeral comes before the smaller numeral we add them
     35     #If the smaller numeral comes before larger number we subtract

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'valid_num2' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: This seems to work well for normal inputs. Which inputs is this problem with?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arise when you first enter at least one invalid numeral and then enter valid ones. You have a problem of scope.

Here is a working fix :

```
import re
def Calculator():    
    raw_input=input("Please enter the calculation you wish to be performed in the necesseary roman numeral format (e.g II + IV ensuring a space between each number and sign): ") #Here we ask for the desired calculation the user wishes to complete

    # assume arguments in the format "VII +II"
    arguments= raw_input.split(" ") #The initial string is then split into three seperate arguments for each separate entity involved in the calculation.
    num1=arguments[0]
    operator = arguments[1] #This indicates that the operator/Command is the second place of our users input which in pyton indices is the 1 space
    num2 = arguments[2] 
    
    status = False  # not yet succeeded

    def Validating(num1):
        return (re.search(r"^M{0,3}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$",num1))\
    
    if Validating(num1):
        if Validating(num2):
            print('Both Numerals accepted')
            valid_num1=num1
            valid_num2=num2
            status = True  # succeed
        else:
            print('The second numeral entered', num2, 'is not a valid numeral please try again!')
    else:
        if Validating(num2):
            print("The first numeral entered", num1, "is not a valid numeral please try again!")
        else:
            print('Both numerals entered', num1, 'and', num2, 'are invalid please try again!')

    def romanToInt(num1): #This function is essential to the running of the calculator as it converts our first number in our calculations from its roman numeral form to its numerical form 
        #When using roman numerals if the larger numeral comes before the smaller numeral we add them
        #If the smaller numeral comes before larger number we subtract
        
            roman= { "I" : 1, "V" : 5, "X" : 10, "L" : 50, "C" : 100, "D" : 500, "M" : 1000 } #Here we pair each base roman numeral with its numerical counterpart
        
            Int=0
        
            for i in range(len(num1)):
                if i+1<len(num1) and roman[num1[i]] < roman[num1[i+1]]:    #i+1<len(num1) checks to see whether the roman numeral present has another roman numeral after it in our order 
                    Int-=roman[num1[i]]    #roman[num1[i]] < roman[num1[i+1]] this compares whether the first roman numeral is larger or smaller than the one that follows. This is extremely important in determining the value of our roman numerals
                else:    #Int-=roman[s[i]] indicates that in this circumstance we must subtract the first roman numeral from our result
                        Int += roman[num1[i]]     #Int +=roman[num1[i]] indicates that if the previous conditions are not met then we are okay to add both roman numerals together
            return Int #After inserting our roman numeral we are left with an integer as our output

    if status:
        Int1=romanToInt(valid_num1)
        Int2=romanToInt(valid_num2)
        
        print(Int1)
        print(Int2)
        print(operator)
    else:
        Calculator()


Calculator()
```